# Discord Bot Won't @ People

Tags: python, discord

I have been making a bot that adds people who react to a message to an array, and then @'s everyone on the array once a goal is met. I have gotten it to send out the message that should @ everyone but it just shows the text instead of actually notifying the people. "Names" is the list that it gathers and "send_out" is supposed to format it.

```
@client.event
async def on_raw_reaction_add(payload):
  if payload.message_id == messageid and payload.member.bot == False:
    if str(payload.emoji.name) == "":
      name = str(payload.member.name + "#" + payload.member.discriminator)
      global count
      count += 1
      global names
      names.append(name)
      print (names)
      if (count == goal_actual):
        print("Goal has been reached.")
        channel = client.get_channel(channel_id)
        await channel.send("We now have " + str(goal_actual) + " for " + game_actual + "!")
        print(channel)
        global send_out
        for x in names:
          send_out += ("@" + x +"  ")
        await channel.send(send_out)
        send_out = []
      else:
        print("Detected reaction from " + name + ". There are is now " , count ,  " people ready.")
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It's best to use the `member` object that `payload` gives you

[Here (discord.py docs)](https://discordpy.readthedocs.io/en/latest/api.html?highlight=on_raw_reaction#discord.on_raw_reaction_add) we can see that `discord.on_raw_reaction_add(payload)` gives a `RawReactionActionEvent` object.

`RawReactionActionEvent` also has a `member` object, which is a normal [member object](https://discordpy.readthedocs.io/en/latest/api.html?highlight=on_raw_reaction#discord.Member), this has an attribute `member.mention`

You could use this instead to tag people

```py
@client.event
async def on_raw_reaction_add(payload):
  if payload.message_id == messageid and payload.member.bot == False:
    if str(payload.emoji.name) == "":
      global count
      count += 1
      global names
      names.append(payload.member)
      print (names)
      if (count == goal_actual):
        print("Goal has been reached.")
        channel = client.get_channel(channel_id)
        await channel.send("We now have " + str(goal_actual) + " for " + game_actual + "!")
        print(channel)
        global send_out
        for member in names:
          send_out += (member.mention)
        await channel.send(send_out)
        send_out = []
      else:
        print("Detected reaction from " + name + ". There are is now " , count ,  " people ready.")
```